# Load wpf Datagrid data in another window text boxes

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I want to repeat datagrid data in textboxes of another window. Data has been saved in sql databse and want to retrieve them on the new window based on click on one datagrid row.
can do?

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,23,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="grdPeople" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                  IsReadOnly="True" DataContext="{Binding}">

            <DataGrid.Columns>                
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="Auto" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Job}" Header="Job" Width="Auto"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Picture" Width="45" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Picture}" Width="30" Height="30" Stretch="Uniform">                                
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using data binding to populate the cells in your DataGrid control, by shuffling around the structure of the data your UI code is binding to (the object your DataContext is bound to), you should be able to achieve what you're going for.

I put together a quick, simplified example. I created the class MyViewModel as the "binding target" and the class MyView to represent your view/xaml. First, MyView, similar to your code above, has a DataGrid. I also added a few text boxes to the same user control, below the DataGrid. Two are the Name and Job fields from the selected item. The other two are supposed to be the *other fields* you want to populate based on the user's selection. For example, they *could be* extra data you look up from the database when the user selects a row. Here's MyView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
              SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job" Binding="{Binding Job}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="2"/>
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Job, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="2"/>
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding ExtraStuff.ExtraIntegerField, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="2"/>
        <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding ExtraStuff.ExtraDoubleField, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now, for the DataGrid's bindings, I bind the ItemsSource to a specific collection on the DataContext of the control. So here, the DataContext is not the collection itself, but instead an object containing both the items for the rows and some other information. I also bind SelectedItem to a property called SelectedItem that should has a public getter and setter. The DataContext of MyView is then set to an instance of MyViewModel. Here is MyViewModel.cs:

```
public sealed class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<LightItem> _items = new ObservableCollection<LightItem>();

    private LightItem _selectedItem;
    private ExtraInformation _extraStuff;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this._items.Add(new LightItem("Tim", "Dish Washer"));
        this._items.Add(new LightItem("Bob", "Window Washer"));
        this._items.Add(new LightItem("Jill", "Widget Washer"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ExtraInformation ExtraStuff
    {
        get { return this._extraStuff; }
        private set
        {
            this._extraStuff = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ExtraStuff");
        }
    }

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<LightItem> Items { get { return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<LightItem>(this._items); } }

    public LightItem SelectedItem
    {
        get { return this._selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            this._selectedItem = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            this.ExtraStuff = new ExtraInformation(value);
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (null != this.PropertyChanged)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public sealed class ExtraInformation
    {
        private readonly double _extraDoubleField;
        private readonly int _extraIntegerField;

        public ExtraInformation(LightItem light)
        {
            // you could get more info for your record from the db
            // but here we just get some random numbers
            var rnd = new Random();
            this._extraDoubleField = rnd.NextDouble();
            this._extraIntegerField = rnd.Next();
        }

        public double ExtraDoubleField { get { return this._extraDoubleField; } }

        public double ExtraIntegerField { get { return this._extraIntegerField; } }
    }

    public sealed class LightItem
    {
        private readonly string _job;
        private readonly string _name;

        public LightItem(string name, string job)
        {
            this._name = name;
            this._job = job;
        }

        public string Job { get { return this._job; } }

        public string Name { get { return this._name; } }
    }
}
```

Here, the property SelectedItem is the same one we bound to the SelectedItem dependency property on the DataGrid. It's type is the same type of item that is in my Items collection, which is bound to the DataGrid's ItemsSource. Now, when the setter of SelectedItem gets called, not only to update it and raise the PropertyChanged event. I also construct a new ExtraInformation object and assign it to ExtrStuff. Looking back at MyView.xaml, you'll see that the two text boxes at the bottom have their TextProperty bound to the integer and double field on this object. Each time the user selects one of these items, a new set of random numbers gets displayed.

While this doesn't take you all the way to looking up information about the selected item from the database, hopefully it points you in the right direction on how you can do this cleanly using WPF data binding. Which Window the text fields are in doesn't matter - in most cases, you should be able to DataContext of both windows to the same underlying MyViewModel. That's the cool part about this approach. The MyViewModel class encapsulates how the information stored in the database about your selected item is looked up. MyView just sees that some of the data it has bound to is updated, and lets MyViewModel know when the user has clicked on a different item in the DataGrid. Really, you structure what the data looks like logically in the binding target. Then you just tell the view portion how to "latch on" with bindings. It also means that different views can "latch on" in different ways. Maybe Window1 has a DataGrid bound to Items, Window2 some text fields bound to both information on SelectedItem and ExtraStuff, and maybe Window3 has an image displayed that is associated with the SelectedItem. Each Window/View just is a different visual representation of the data in the binding target (a MyViewModel instance here).

Here's a simple diagram demonstrating the idea:

[image: quick Paint diagram of data binding from two views to one viewmodel, on different windows]

Comment: I threw a similar example that actually has two windows with full source here. Feel free to check it out if you'd like.

https://github.com/tlantz/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/MultiWindowMasterDetail/MultiWindowMasterDetail

Answer (score 0):

Iused this method, made a ChildWindow and used LINQ to SQL classes

```
<TextBox Width="100" Height="40" Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
                 Margin="371,192,84,29"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="40" Name="txtFamily" Text="{Binding Family, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
                 Margin="228,192,226,29"></TextBox>
```

and a button for main page that contains DataGrid:

```
private void btnNewWin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                ChildWindow chWin = new ChildWindow { Owner = this, DataContext = this.dataGrid1.SelectedItem };
                chWin.ShowDialog();

            }
        }
```

When Button was clicked, data display on textBoxes as well, but when i add Picture this way, not work!